# How to validate id_token without using any library

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have successfully implemented OpenID Connect in java. Only part remaining is validated id_token. I have decoded the id_token using base64 and fetched the user email and name. Now I want to validate the id_token so that I can use that user details.  Can anyone help me in validating the id_token?

I have tried below code to validate id_token

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ValidateIdToken {
    public static final String id_token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjRlMjVjMTQ2Y2Y4NmU2MGM4ODYxNDdlYWQyNzBlYzAxYTllODU1YTEifQ.eyJhenAiOiIyODQzNDYxNzE1OTEtMGxtOGphamkwOW9iMzNuM2h1bXRrOXYyMzczcjgxcnEuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiIyODQzNDYxNzE1OTEtMGxtOGphamkwOW9iMzNuM2h1bXRrOXYyMzczcjgxcnEuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDk0NjgzNjY4OTQ1NjQwMDU3MzgiLCJoZCI6ImluZm9vYmplY3RzLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoia2lzaG9yZS5zdXRoYXJAaW5mb29iamVjdHMuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF0X2hhc2giOiJod255SGc0dnlrOTZXVUxZYktyRTl3IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk4NDc5MDIyLCJleHAiOjE0OTg0ODI2MjIsIm5hbWUiOiJLaXNob3JlIFN1dGhhciIsInBpY3R1cmUiOiJodHRwczovL2xoNS5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20vLXJNb3kzeEpfRHA4L0FBQUFBQUFBQUFJL0FBQUFBQUFBQUFBL0FJNnlHWHp5WXdoeXMtU0FwVnhodDBJbTFOQktlYXpZa0Evczk2LWMvcGhvdG8uanBnIiwiZ2l2ZW5fbmFtZSI6Iktpc2hvcmUiLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6IlN1dGhhciIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuIn0.iWJquu48swut8denWospcnOu-0QpQjWrw7d_K7lDdtwJ6xo6zE1rnmoOHw1xxeWrE9e2Vy-AqJ4mLHYn3rGoRe026oWLvwQMAgcNmhBENwvd9kAbYZukg_J7Ypy2Srnsu97u0q-QTAs3MBmxO0Yp2bHwuR5gmwEvTaE6gTtSZOf_Tg5FyrqaZgdrBuXxxLvQqHsNXIp4MxthxBtAH1kGo_KBrVAoKH1dRkKzsjSlt73nB_uKODGe2FoUwrNybItp9t5xE653pnxp2L6rbLJ2U9TU3gGSQ5yDdWPMt-AIAGJ7d1WOIHHGpN9FcT3KYEueS0j0h6Kfktr5XCCYnuEwQg";
    public static final String[] id_token_parts = id_token.split("\\.");

    public static final String MODULUS = "5SGw1jcqyFYEZaf39RoxAhlq-hfRSOsneVtsT2k09yEQhwB2myvf3ckVAwFyBF6y0Hr1psvu1FlPzKQ9YfcQkfge4e7eeQ7uaez9mMQ8RpyAFZprq1iFCix4XQw-jKW47LAevr9w1ttZY932gFrGJ4gkf_uqutUny82vupVUETpQ6HDmIL958SxYb_-d436zi5LMlHnTxcR5TWIQGGxip-CrD7vOA3hrssYLhNGQdwVYtwI768EvwE8h4VJDgIrovoHPH1ofDQk8-oG20eEmZeWugI1K3z33fZJS-E_2p_OiDVr0EmgFMTvPTnQ75h_9vyF1qhzikJpN9P8KcEm8oGu7KJGIn8ggUY0ftqKG2KcWTaKiirFFYQ981PhLHryH18eOIxMpoh9pRXf2y7DfNTyid99ig0GUH-lzAlbKY0EV2sIuvEsIoo6G8YT2uI72xzl7sCcp41FS7oFwbUyHp_uHGiTZgN7g-18nm2TFmQ_wGB1xCwJMFzjIXq1PwEjmg3W5NBuMLSbG-aDwjeNrcD_4vfB6yg548GztQO2MpV_BuxtrZDJQm-xhJXdm4FfrJzWdwX_JN9qfsP0YU1_mxtSU_m6EKgmwFdE3Yh1WM0-kRRSk3gmNvXpiKeVduzm8I5_Jl7kwLgBw24QUVaLZn8jC2xWRk_jcBNFFLQgOf9U";
    public static final String EXPONENT = "AQAB";

    public static final String ID_TOKEN_HEADER = base64UrlDecode(id_token_parts[0]);
    public static final String ID_TOKEN_PAYLOAD = base64UrlDecode(id_token_parts[1]);
    public static final byte[] ID_TOKEN_SIGNATURE = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(id_token_parts[2]);

    public static String base64UrlDecode(String input) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(input);
        String result = new String(decodedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] base64UrlDecodeToBytes(String input) {
        Base64 decoder = new Base64(-1, null, true);
        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(input);

        return decodedBytes;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        validateToken();
    }

    public static void validateToken() {
        PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey(MODULUS, EXPONENT);
        byte[] data = (id_token_parts[0] + "." + id_token_parts[1]).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        try {
            boolean isSignatureValid = verifyUsingPublicKey(data, ID_TOKEN_SIGNATURE, publicKey);
            System.out.println("isSignatureValid: " + isSignatureValid);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String MODULUS, String EXPONENT) {
        byte[] nb = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(MODULUS);
        byte[] eb = base64UrlDecodeToBytes(EXPONENT);
        BigInteger n = new BigInteger(1, nb);
        BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, eb);

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(n, e);
        try {
            PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);

            return publicKey;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cant create public key", ex);
        }
    }

    private static boolean verifyUsingPublicKey(byte[] data, byte[] signature, PublicKey pubKey)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pubKey);
        sig.update(data);

        return sig.verify(signature);
    }
}
```

error

```
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 512
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:189)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1219)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:652)
    at com.certain.sso.handler.ValidateIdToken.verifyUsingPublicKey(ValidateIdToken.java:75)
    at com.certain.sso.handler.ValidateIdToken.validateToken(ValidateIdToken.java:45)
    at com.certain.sso.handler.ValidateIdToken.main(ValidateIdToken.java:37)
```

Comment: Please add info about the programming language you use and what problem you had with Nimbus and other libraries.

Comment: @Ján Halaša  updated question

Comment: I tried to create the public key out of the MODULUS and EXPONENT, but the MODULUS value seems to be an invalid Base64 string. I get `Illegal base64 character 2d` from `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(MODULUS)`.

Comment: do you have any other way to validate the id_token?

Answer (score 0):

The Java exception is due to your signature, that has not been correctly computed:
The "HS256" alg parameter in your ID token header does not simply mean that you need to compute the SHA-256 hash and "encrypt" it with the RSA private key, then encode it with base64 and fill it at the end of the ID token.

HS256 means you need to use the PKCS#1 "SHA256withRSA" algorithm, fully specified by RFC-8017. According to this RFC, the signature must have the same length in octets than the RSA modulus. Your RSA modulus is 512 bytes length, so the signature part of your ID token MUST be 512 bytes length. Even if the hash function (HMAC-SHA256) returns values of 256 bits length.

So, to compute a 512 bytes length signature from a 256 bits length HMAC-SHA256 hash, RFC-8017 requires you to use the I2OSP Integer-to-Octet-String primitive, that takes 2 arguments: your 256 bits hash, and the integer 512 (the length of your RSA modulus). I2OSP will output a 512 bytes length octet string, that you must finally give to sig.verify() as a parameter.